# git negation of excluding hidden directory with hidden files

Tags: linux, git, gitignore

I manage config files in my home directory with git.
Here is the simplified content of the `.gitignore` file in my home directory.

```
*
!.bashrc
!.bash_aliases
!.gitignore
```

I created a new directory in my home directory `.bashrc_includes` with several files:

```
.bashrc_includes/
├── .bashrc_android
├── .bashrc_asdf
└── .bashrc_sdkman
```

I would like to add this directory with all the files inside it to the repository. I tried to add `!.bashrc_includes/*` to my `.gitignore`, but look like it is still ignored by git.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `!.bashrc_includes/*` will exclude the files from the ignored files, but the directory itself is still ignored!

The following `.gitignore` allows you to exclude the directory and the files inside from the ignored files:

```
*
!.bashrc
!.bashrc_includes/*
!.bashrc_includes/
!.bash_aliases
!.gitignore
```

You can find some more in-depth explanations in this question: [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder).